# Is it possible to double crit?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, rogue, damage, critical-hit

My question is related to rogue archetype assassin. On surprise rounds if I hit a creature it is automatically a critical hit. But what if I rolled a natural 20 on attack during surprise round? Does that count as double critical hit?

I'm asking this because on lv 17 assassin gets *Death Strike* that doubles the damage dealt when you attack and hit a creature that is surprised, it must make a Constitution saving throw (DC 8 + your Dexterity modifier + your proficiency bonus). On a failed save, double the damage of your attack against the creature. So that is damage rolled x4 by the rules, so if you roll a nat 20 on a surprise attack does that make it x6?

Answer (score 9):

There is no concept of double critical in DnD 5e. A hit is either a critical hit or not, and the rogue's abilities only grant additional ways to make a hit critical.

Also note that doubled damage caused by Death Strike literally means that any damage you inflict is doubled. Unlike critical hits, you don't roll extra dice because of this feature - you roll the damage, including any critical hit bonus dice, as usual, add any modifiers and then double the damage.

Answer (score 4):

No, not according to the base rules for critical hits. There is no mention of a "double critical" hit anywhere in the Players Handbook.